# The IF argument

Tags: java, if-statement

```
            if (array[r][0].equals("Buy")){
                System.out.println(array[r][0]);
                for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)              
                    Buys[r][i] = array[r][i];
            }
        }
    if (array[r][0]==("Sell")){
        System.out.println(array[r][0]);
        for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)              
            Sales[r][i] =array[r][i];
    }
```

i'm try to figure out how the argument works and the way i always use the argument is either `==`, `=<`, `=>`, `!=`. but now i'm tryin to use a `.equals` for an array to work, but it seems there is no error. so am i havin any Syntax Error? or am i using it wrong?

For more info of what i was tryin to do, is i'm tryin to make the argument to see if it equals Buy or Sell, it goes thru. but i tried == and .equals ... doesn't do anything
I TRIED ,equals on "buy" part it still wont' go thru

```
            if (array[r][0].equals("Buy")){
                System.out.println(array[r][0]);
                for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)              
                    Buys[r][i] = array[r][i];
            }
```

i switched ALL to .equals, but for some reasong it forces me to go thru this line

```
if (array[r][0] != null)
```

before this

```
        if (array[r][0] != null)
        for ( r = 0; r < 165; r++){
            System.out.println(array[r][0]);
            if (array[r][0].equalsIgnoreCase("Buy")){
                System.out.println(array[r][0]);
                for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)              
                    Buys[r][i] = array[r][i];
            }
        }
    if (array[r][0].equalsIgnoreCase("Sell")){
        System.out.println(array[r][0]);
        for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)              
            Sales[r][i] =array[r][i];
    }
```

so why do i need this line to make this work, cuz apparently it stops it to thru that IF statement

Comment: I have a suspicion that your problem might not be with `==` or `equals`. The line `if (array[r][0] != null)` I suspect will never return true, because `r` is equal to 165 by this point, but `array[165]` never gets set.

Comment: it forces me to add a null on that string, what should i replace it with, or do i even need that line to just skip to that for loop

Answer (score 1):

THe "argument" to `if` is a *boolean expression* -- an expression whose value is of type `boolean`, which can be either `true` or `false`. Those operators (`==`, etc) return boolean values, as does the `equals()` method, and many other methods like the `contains()` method in the `List` interface. You can also write boolean methods yourself.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is

```
if(-something-that-evaluates-to-boolean)
```

so things that evaluate to boolean such as `(a < 1)` or `(b == 1)` can be uses. Also anything that returns boolean can also be used. In your case, `equals()` returns boolean and that's why it works and the usage is  perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never name your arrays 'array'.  It does not convey any meaningful information
2. Strings are objects, not primitives.  You should always compare them using `.equals()` unless you really know what you're [doing](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html).  It's not a matter of syntax, it's a matter of [semantics](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html).

Answer (score 0):

You still have `if (array[r][0]==("Sell"))`. Make it use `equals(..)`. Strings in java can't be compared with `==`

Note: of course, as every object, `==` comparison can be done. But with strings it won't work unless you are using interned strings (that is, the same object for the same string contents)

Comment: What do you mean?  Sure they can - and it can be effective if your Strings are interned().  I'm not saying one should do this, but it certainly *can* be done.

Comment: was trying both, and it still but i have one at lookin for "Buy" to see which one it takes, but both didn't work

Comment: @Amir Afghani of course, but I didn't want to complicate my answer with that, at least initially.

Comment: I figured as much, I just wanted to talk back to the guy with 100k+ rep! :)

Comment: @user604995 you have that at two places. Make sure you use equals on both.

Answer (score 0):

The argument in an `if` statement must be something that is either `true` or `false`. This means you can use any relational operator (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) or any method that returns a `boolean` type.

All objects have an `equals` method available, which returns `boolean` and is supposed to return `true` if two objects are "equal", for however you like to define equality for a given kind of object. (For example, two strings that have the same length and characters are equal) So this is a perfectly valid argument for `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use == to compare Strings in Java. Use String.equals, String.equalsIgnoreCase or String.compareTo

Comment: yes i was tryin all i know that i was use to, but i still tried 

    if (array[r][0].equals("Buy")){
     System.out.println(array[r][0]);
     for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)              
      Buys[r][i] = array[r][i];
    }

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the array (array[r][0]) could be empty. The default value of a Stringarray is null, and since null doesn't exist, one can't call functions on it.

But for both "Buy" and "Sell" you know they exist and cannot be null. Therefore it would be better to replace
    array[r][0].equals("Buy")
with
    "Buy".equals(array[r][0])

That way you won't have to check in advance if array[r][0] is null, since the equals does this for you.

One of the reasons you can't use == to check for string equality is because the String is an object, and in this case the == operator checks whether the memory address is the same for both string. Most of the time this is not the case. The equals operator recognizes that the object is a String and checks whether the contents of the String-object are the same.